# How to get id of button inside main div when I clicked on button?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events

I have added onclick on main div. Whenever I click on its child elements, main div onclick is trigger. I cannot get id of the child element I clicked inside the main div using `this`.

Here is sample

```
<div id = 'main' onclick='console.log(this);'>
  <p> some paragraph </p>
  ...
  <button id='test' type="button">click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function by passing the *event*. Then use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to get the *id*.

**Demo:**

```html
<div id = 'main' onclick='handleClick(event);'>
  <p> some paragraph </p>
  
  <button id='test' type="button">click</button>
</div>

<script>
  function handleClick(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Correct. Thanks. I found some code: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_target